# How to further search the Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I made an example database at the bottom of this question.

In my Admin application I would like to be able to search directly for the status of the user.

If I do a search by Key I must go to the Users then the user-1 and finally This method is a big problem if I have several dozen or more users.

Does anyone have a method so that I can directly find user statuses and not go through children (which would be impossible)**

**If not, is there a search text where I can directly search for what I want ?

Obviously I want a method that displays all the wrong statuses or just the statuses.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Firebase queries work on a flat list of child nodes, where the value you search for must be at a fixed path under each direct child node.

So in your data structure, you can search across all users for `infos-1/statut` with:

```
ref("users").orderByChild("infos-1/statut").equalTo(true)
```

Or you can search across all `infos-*` nodes for `user-1` with:

```
ref("users/user-1").orderByChild("statut").equalTo(true)
```

You cannot however search across all users for all `infos-*` nodes.

For more on this, also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)